# Scrapy (Python) throws ImportError when running with cron

Tags: python, python-2.7, cron, scrapy

I'm running a scrapy spider with cron, but it throws an ImportError exception:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/som/scrapy_testing/scrapy_testing/spiders/hm_spiders.py", line 2, in <module>
    import scrapy
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/scrapy/__init__.py", line 48, in <module>
    from scrapy.spiders import Spider
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/scrapy/spiders/__init__.py", line 10, in <module>
    from scrapy.http import Request
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/scrapy/http/__init__.py", line 12, in <module>
    from scrapy.http.request.rpc import XmlRpcRequest
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/scrapy/http/request/rpc.py", line 7, in <module>
    from six.moves import xmlrpc_client as xmlrpclib
ImportError: cannot import name xmlrpc_client
```

The strange thing is that when I run the script that is being run by cron it works fine.

The cron is set as

```
*   *   *   *   *   sh /Users/som/sh/hm_scraping.sh
```

and the script is

```
#!/bin/bash
python /Users/som/scrapy_testing/scrapy_testing/spiders/hm_spiders.py
```

I'm using the CrawlerProcess class as described here: http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/practices.html

```
process = CrawlerProcess({
    'USER_AGENT': 'Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 5.1)'
})
process.crawl(HmSpider)
process.start()
```

================================================
EDIT

Based on MuhammadTahir and lapinkoira comments I tested the following directly in the terminal:

```
/usr/bin/python /Users/som/scrapy_testing/scrapy_testing/spiders/hm_spiders.py
```

and

```
sudo -u som /usr/bin/python /Users/som/scrapy_testing/scrapy_testing/spiders/hm_spiders.py
```

The first one runs fine, but when I use sudo (I've ran without setting the user as well) it returns the same problem. Maybe cron uses sudo in the background.

Any ideas??

Thanks!

Comment: Do you use a virtualenv? which user runs the cron and which user runs the script?

Comment: Using complete path (`/usr/bin/python` or `/path/to/venv/python`) to `python` binary instead of just `python` in your `hm_scraping.sh` should resolve it.

Comment: @MuhammadTahir, it didn't work.

Comment: @lapinkoira, I guess it's "som". I ran `sudo crontab -u som -e` and the settings were there, when I ran `sudo crontab -u root -e` it was empty. Also it sends an "e-mail" to /var/mail/som.

Comment: Have you tried running the script as som's user manually? like su - som -c "execute script"

Comment: The way you put it also doesn't work, but it works if I remove the dash, though. I've also ran using sudo with and without specified user, and both of them presented error. And I also ran python script directly (without using sh script)  for all combination, just to find out that it has no difference.

By the way, the user also don't seem to be the issue, since it faults both on _som_ and _root_ when I use sudo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would try one of both:

1- Activate the env first:

```
source /path/of/your/venv/bin/activate && /path/of/your/venv/bin/python /Users/som/scrapy_testing/scrapy_testing/spiders/hm_spiders.py
```

2- or without activating the env (may not work):

```
/path/of/your/venv/bin/python /Users/som/scrapy_testing/scrapy_testing/spiders/hm_spiders.py
```

Comment: It worked!! I figure the user permissions are all crazy in my computer, since I'm not so sure how and when to use sudo. What a surprise, the problem was... well... the user... =P

Thanks!